# Taking a list of tuples and printing them in a two column format with a first line header

Tags: python, printing, formatting

```
def initialize_portfolio(portfolio):
    with open('holdings.txt') as file:
        portfolio = [line.split() for line in file]
        return portfolio

def print_portfolio(portfolio):
    print('Symbol Amount')
    for symbol, amt in portfolio:
        print(f'{symbol:6} {amt:6}')
```

i have also tried:

```
 titleSymbol = 'Symbol'
 titeAmount = 'Amount'
 for Atuple in zip(portfolio):
   print('%s  %s \n' %(titleSymbol, titeAmount), Atuple)
```

neither code is giving me the correct format I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

File:

[image]

Comment: `initialize_portfolio()` expects each line of the file to be a pair of space-separated numbers. It doesn't look like that's what you have. Show a few lines of the file.

Comment: just edited post with a pic of the txt file

Comment: Plain text is better than pictures.

Comment: The default delimiter in `split()` is whitespace. Use `split(',')` to split on commas. Or use the `csv` module.